Can't use "Rounded Window Corners" Extension on GNOME 46! Can anyone please suggest a workaround?
I am new to GNOME 46. I installed Extension Manager App and couldn't find it there. So, I searched for it on GNOME Extensions Website, found it and clicked on Install. The Extension Manager App opened with the exact Extension saying it is not compatible with the current version of GNOME.
So, can anyone here offer me a workaround? I am a native Windows 11 and MacBook user and hate to see anything having rough edges on my computer. I installed Ubuntu 24.04 thinking that Linux offers the most wide ranges of customization, but unable to do this simple thing makes me doubt this statement.
I mean there is only one extension for this purpose as well! No variety to choose from...
Any help will be appreciated!

You can find a workaround in the first comment here https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5237/rounded-window-corners/

@vanadium I tried that, but failed to achieve any result. If you could help me in any way with to do it in a particular correct manner, I'll be grateful to you!

You can try using the Rounded Windows Corners Reborn extension, as it supports GNOME 46 and should work fine for your setup. It provides the same functionality as the extension you're trying to use, with rounded corners for your windows.
You can download it from the GNOME Extensions website here: Rounded Windows Corners Reborn
